# jquery animate rainbow-like color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, gif

Let's say i have this image:

[image: animated line]

The line color is a gradient from yellow to purple.
Now my question is this: is there a way to either create a gif or use jquery or other form of javascript to make a non stop animation of the colours changing from left to right?

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be done using sprite animation.

Basically, you can use jQuery to rapidly change the background position of an element giving the illusion of animation.

There's a simple little plugin for this already, but one can also be written yourself quite easily.

http://spritely.net/documentation/

Comment: Yes. Absolutely perfect! This will definitely make life easier. Thanks :)